# Adding input value as a string in function

Tags: javascript, jquery

basically, I am making a first function that gets the value of an input on the click of a button. Then, I am trying to create an event that will add that value to a function on the click of the button.

```
 var getInput = function() {
$('#inputSubmit').click(function() {
    return $('input[name=input1]').val(); 
    });  };

var addTextInTextBox_1 = function(text) {
    $("#textBox").append("<p>"+text+"</p>");
$('#inputSubmit').on('click', addTextInTextBox_1("Good, your character's name is " + getInput()));
```

However, I keep getting a p equal to: "Good, your character's name is undefined. I understand that it is because the function is taking to input.
I just don't know how to make the function wait until I click on the button to execute the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to bind `click` again inside `getInput`:

```
var getInput = function(){
    return $('input[name=input1]').val(); 
};
```

Note also your original code didn't return any value (hence, `undefined`): your `return` was inside the `click`-bound anonymous function.

To put it all together:

```
var getInput = function(){
    return $('input[name=input1]').val(); 
};
var addTextInTextBox_1 = function(text){
    $("#textBox").append("<p>"+text+"</p>");
};
$('#inputSubmit').on('click', addTextInTextBox_1("Good, your character's name is " + getInput()));
```